# Use basic auth for different URIs in a .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication

My problem is the following. I have several URIs that I need to put behind a basic authentication, preferably using the .htaccess file. I have done this using the Location directive in the httpd.conf file, but this is far from ideal.

So my ideal world would be this:

URI1 => user1, pwd1

URI2 -> user2, pwd2

URI3 -> no auth

URI4 -> user3, pwd3

I've seen some solutions using an env variable, but it seems to me that those can only be of binary use, either you get authenticated by a general htpasswd file, or you don't. My solution would have to have different users per different URI.

If my problem isn't thoroughly explained let me know.

Comment: Can't be solved by a .htaccess solution. Thanks for the confirmation though!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `<Location>` container, you can use the `<Files>` container instead to match a specific file that is *inside the directory that the request is for*. It'll work the same way.

For example, if you have a directory "foo" and "bar", and inside those directories, you have files "type1.php" and "type2.php", then you'd have an htaccess file in "foo" that looks like:

```
<Files "type1.php">
# htpasswd stuff
Require user user1
</Files>

<Files "type2.php">
# htpasswd stuff
Require user user2
</Files>
```

then in the "bar" directory:

```
<Files "type1.php">
# htpasswd stuff
Require user user3
</Files>

<Files "type2.php">
# htpasswd stuff
Require user user4
</Files>
```

Comment: Hi Jon, the URIs are dynamicall built as web URIs (Laravel web app). Our current auth provider doesn't allow us to set different users for different URIs. So based on file will not work since the URIs are rewritten.

Comment: @JanVansteenlandt don't think you can do this in htaccess then, as you can't indicate any sort of paths in containers, and I don't think you can use any trickery with env variables.

Comment: Yea, was afraid that might be the case, never excluded that there wasn't one. Thanks though for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put a .htaccess file where each different URI is so...

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Then inside the .htpasswd file you have:

```
user:password
```

Obviously you would want to encrypt the password

I think this is what you are asking for?

Comment: Same reply as my reply to Jon's answer, the URIs are dynamically built. It's basically a webapp, but the auth provider doesn't allow for the auth functionality I'm looking for.